# Return 0 on count()

Tags: mysql

I've seen similar questions but a lot of them are different situations and I just can't get it working like I want it to so I came here for some help.

The user has several cities they've lived in a certain period.

How can I get count to return 0 to all the other cities that they've belonged to but are outside `BETWEEN` dates?

```
SELECT cityname, COUNT( cityname ) AS city_count

FROM cities

LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON cities.id = people.cityid

WHERE firstname =  'John' AND lastname =  'Doe'

AND RESIDENCY_DATE

BETWEEN  '1996-08-01'

AND  '1997-05-31'

GROUP BY cityname
```

Query Output:

```
    city | city_count
  ___________________

  cali          1
  seattle       2
```

Expected output:

```
    city | city_count
  ___________________

  cali          1
  seattle       2
  washington    0
  new york      0
```

And etc.

I'd like it to count whatever's in between the dates but return 0 to all the other cities they've lived in.

(Which would all the rows in `people.cityid` column)

Comment: What is the table structure for the two tables? In which table are each of the columns? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.  Also took the liberty of cleaning up the BETWEEN logic to ensure it matches up to and including 1997-05-31.

This will select all cities, and then count up people which match the criteria specifically

```
SELECT 
    cities.cityname, 
    COALESCE(COUNT( inTimePeriod.id ),0) AS city_count

FROM cities

// Find all cities the user has lived in

INNER JOIN people AS hasLivedIn
    ON hasLivedIn.cityid = cities.id
    AND people.firstname =  'John'
    AND people.lastname =  'Doe'

// Now rejoin the ones that they've lived in in the specified time

LEFT JOIN people AS inTimePeriod
    ON inTimePeriod.cityid = hasLivedIn.cityid
    AND inTimePeriod.RESIDENCY_DATE BETWEEN DATE('1996-08-01') AND DATE('1997-05-31')

GROUP BY cities.cityname
```

Comment: Oh why hello there again :) I thought you went to bed? ;) Also, you keep using keywords I haven't heard of before!

Comment: I woke up ;)  And it's always nice to pluck a new one out of thin air - just make sure it's not a typo :D

Comment: Thanks again, took me a bit to get it right. The column names weren't exactly the same but it all worked out in the end. Can't thank you enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**COUNT(DISTINCT)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) it returns 0 if there were no matching rows.

Try below :

```
  SELECT cityname, COUNT( distinct cityname ) AS city_count
  FROM cities
  LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON cities.id = people.cityid
  WHERE firstname =  'John' AND lastname =  'Doe'
  AND RESIDENCY_DATE
  BETWEEN  '1996-08-01'
  AND  '1997-05-31'
  GROUP BY cityname
```